# How to check a.pem is signed by rootca.pem and a_key.pem is the private key of a.pem?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

Suppose there is root certificate named **rootca.pem**, its private key is **rootca_key.pem**.

And there are a certificate named **a.pem** and a private key named **a_key.pem**.

How to check(using openssl or any other way):

1. **a.pem** is signed by **rootca.pem**?
2. **a_key.pem** is really the private key of **a.pem**?

Comment: Q1 `openssl verify -trusted rootca.pem a.pem` or see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118062/use-openssl-to-individually-verify-components-of-a-certificate-chain for the general case Q2 see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56697/determine-if-private-key-belongs-to-certificate and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-can-you-check-if-a-private-key-and-certificate-match-in-openssl-with-ecdsa . Consider posting security questions on security.SE.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).